# How can I insert a line break into the FIRST space using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, insert, line-breaks

I have this text:

```
05/02/2019 06:07 PM
```

Which I want to display as:

```
05/02/2019
<br>
06:07 PM
```

I am currently using the following function:

```
$('td.lastupdated').html(function(i, v) {
    return v.replace(' ', '<br />');
});
```

But it is giving me this result:

```
05/02/2019
<br>
06:07
<br>
PM
```

How can I target only the ***first*** *space* and insert a line break?

Comment: '05/02/2019 06:07 PM'.replace(/ /, '<br>')

Comment: `return v.replace(//, '<br />');` didn't do anything. `return v.replace(/ /, '<br />');` returned the same result as my original code above.

Comment: `'05/02/2019 06:07 PM'.replace(/ /, '<br>') ` in your browser console returns: `"05/02/2019<br>06:07 PM"`.  Which is not what you said your original code above does.

Comment: Hmmm I see that you are correct, @Taplar. And yet this is how it is rendered on my webpage: `<td class="osta_lastupdated">05/02/2019<br>06:07<br>PM</td>`

Comment: Er, I had it wrapped in a media query.

`$(window).resize(function(){
 if ($(window).width() <= 800){ 
  // do something here
 } 
});`

When I remove the media query it works as you predicted. I'm a total noob. Thanks for your help.